# Set form minimum size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# form with a sizable border. I'd like to set the minimum size to (850, 760) (the default starting size), but when I try to set the value in the form properties menu it keeps changing it to (850, 720). I tried setting it by code as follows:

```
this.minimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(850, 760);
```

but when I run the code I can still shrink my form vertically. Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

EDIT: I'm using two monitors, one standard 1280x1024 and the other widescreen 1366x768, could that be the problem? In that case is there some way to test the user's monitor resolution and set the minimum size based on that?

Comment: `this.miniumSize` - miniumSize is spelled incorrectly. It should be minimum but I feel like that's just a post typo as that would raise an error in an IDE.

Comment: yes, that's a typo; the code does compile

Comment: Keep in mind that the minimum size property does not prevent the user from resizing the form.

Comment: It sounds to me like the form's actual size is set to (850, 720).  Make sure that's set to (850, 760), and you should then be able to set the minimum.  (MinimumSize always has to be <= Size.)

Comment: Maybe you have some auto-generated code wich resizes the form to 850,720?

Comment: MSDN says : Form.MinimumSize Gets or sets the minimum size the form can be resized to.

Comment: @RyanGates: Yes I still want the user to be able to resize the form, just not too small.

Comment: Have you put this command in the designer?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: The size property is (850, 760) in the form property window, and I don't think I'm setting it anywhere else.

Comment: It really feels like you have [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) set to true on the form.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: `AutoSize` is set to false.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010+ you can enable Intellitrace and hook the form's `SizeChanged` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the code that runs at runtime is active at design time as well.  That gives the Winforms designer a very nice WYSIWYG user interface, but it does have some unfortunate side-effects.  Including crashing the designer and giving you the White Screen of Darn.  Or crashing VS to the desktop if you trip this website's name.

This is one such side-effect, the runtime code limits the MinimumSize to the Screen.WorkingArea and does so at design time as well.  Just try typing in (0, 3000) to see that happening.  You can force it by assigning the property in code.

Comment: Interesting. So if I understand correctly, setting the minimum height by code (as I did) would give the desired results on a machine that doesn't use a widescreen monitor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  The normal usage is that you set MinimumSize to the minimum size where the window is still usable.  And also set AutoScroll to True so that a user with a small monitor that doesn't fit MinimumSize can still get to controls that are off the screen.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to accomplish, although I wasn't aware of the AutoScroll feature.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look your code again.It should look like this in the designer or the page_load of your form.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(300,300);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set **FormBorderStyle** property of form to **FixedSingle**. Then form border resizing will be disabled

Comment: I don't want to disable resizing. I want to set a minimum size; the user can make it larger if they wish.

Comment: Hi, After set the minimum size (for eg: 400,500) in property menu,can you able to decrease its width and height than 400,500 ?

Comment: No, the `minimumSize` property works as expected, I'm just not able to set it to the value I want.